# Excel FIltering by multiple criterias

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm am trying to filter a report by patients who have been seen 2021 but if the patient had visits in previous years too I want to exclude them from the report. (so if the patient has been seen in 2018 & 2021 I don't want them to pull) I also want the number in another column to be greater equal to and greater then 10.0

Column B = service date
Column C = patient names
Column F = number indicator

What is the best way to filter this or an =IF formula?

This is a healthcare report so I cannot provide what the report looks like because of patient information.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser ! share some sample data, this should be easy enough using a helper column, or even the rarely used advanced filtering option.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, this could be done through a helper column using a formula that looks like this one:

```
=AND(F2>=10,COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,B:B,"<"&DATE(2021,1,1))=0)
```

Make sure to adjust the references `F2` and `C2` to match whatever the row is where you paste the formula. After that, you can copy up & down that column and those references will update automatically. Here's the barebones of how it works:

`AND()` requires all the conditions inside to be true or else it returns false. We have 2 conditions:

- `F2>=10` is straightforward.
- `COUNTIFS()` counts how many records meet multiple criteria. They comes in range+condition pairs and there are two of them.:

  - `C:C,C2` only counts those values from the entire column C that match the value in this row (the patient's name on this row)
  - `B:B,"<"&DATE(2021,1,1)` only counts those dates that are before 2021-01-01, i.e. before 2021.

If the `COUNTIFS()` returns 0 (meaning it didn't find the patient in any earlier years) and the number in F is greater than or equal to 10, then the `AND()` function will return true. Otherwise, it returns false.

Copy/paste the formula to every row of your table and then filter by that column. You want the ones that returned true.

Answer (score 0):

please check if the following information is helpful to you.

```
=IF(D4>=10,IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C4,$C$10:$C$13,1,FALSE)),B4:D4,""),"")
```

After the Result table is generated, only copy the Value of the Result table to a new. Then refer to [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/delete-blank-rows.html) to delete all blank rows.

[image]